# Styling dropdown options in Angular Material menu

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to implement a dropdown menu for my project using Angular Material (MatMenuModule and MatButtonModule). My HTML is as follows:

```
<p>
        Display the daily data for a different year:
        <button mat-button class="selectYearButton" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Select year</button>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item class="yearOptionButton" *ngFor="let year of years" (click)="updateDailyChart(year)">{{year}}</button>
        </mat-menu>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.selectYearButton {
    background-color: gainsboro;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: .05rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.yearOptionButton {
    height: 10px !important;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
[some irrelevant imports]

@Component({
  selector: 'app-highchart-daily-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './highchart-daily-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./highchart-daily-dropdown.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HighchartDailyDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dataService: DataService) {
  }

  years: Array<number> = [1999, [...], 2022];
 [some other code]
}


}
```

The issue is that most of the styles on .selectYearButton and virtually all styles on .yearOptionButton (except making the text italic) do not work. The way the dropdown menu looks now is way too massive compared to the rest of the text, plus it doesn't look nice as the fonts do not match.

Here is a screenshot: https://ibb.co/TrqqSz4

I tried finding the answer on Google but the documentation for Angular Material is scarce and most of what I found in other forum threads did not work for me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What version of material are u using? I suggest u to inspect your html code and find the classes used for that specific button.
Usually u can modify your style adding

```
.mat-button.mat-primary {
    //your style here
}
```

Please read the docs for more information https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles#styling-concepts

Css classes name can change base on the material version u're using